# Why this code from Fest showing error?

Tags: java, swing, testing, applet, fest

I am trying to learn Java Fest. I took the piece of code from : http://docs.codehaus.org/display/FEST/Getting+Started

```
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import org.fest.swing.fixture.FrameFixture;

public class FirstGUITest {

  private FrameFixture window;

  @BeforeClass public void setUpOnce() {
    FailOnThreadViolationRepaintManager.install();
  }

  @BeforeMethod public void setUp() {
    MyFrame frame = GuiActionRunner.execute(new GuiQuery<MyFrame>() {
        protected MyFrame executeInEDT() {
          return new MyFrame(); 
        }
    });
    window = new FrameFixture(frame);
    window.show(); // shows the frame to test
  }

  @AfterMethod public void tearDown() {
    window.cleanUp();
  }

  @Test public void shouldCopyTextInLabelWhenClickingButton() {
    window.textBox("textToCopy").enterText("Some random text");
    window.button("copyButton").click();
    window.label("copiedText").requireText("Some random text");
  }
}
```

In eclipse, this code shows some error. I have to import

```
import org.fest.swing.edt.FailOnThreadViolationRepaintManager;
```

despite that it shows error on this part :

```
  @BeforeMethod public void setUp() {
    MyFrame frame = GuiActionRunner.execute(new GuiQuery<MyFrame>() {
        protected MyFrame executeInEDT() {
          return new MyFrame(); 
        }
    });
```

it shows error on Myframe. Can anyone explain me what is the reason for this? Thanks in advance.

EDIT : I associated following jars with my project :

1. fest-swing-testng-1.2
2. fest-swing-1.2

**The error is:**

```
MyFrame can not be resolved to a type.
```

Comment: You should post the actual error message.

Comment: The error is "MyFrame can not be resolved to a type."

Comment: This suggests that you could be missing an import or a class. Is MyFrame a core type of the fest library? If so, do you import it? If not, is it a class that you've created?

Comment: I did not create the MyFrame class. It should be from fest library. I almost attached all the jar files downloaded with fest. But it still shows error. Anyway to find out, which jar file to add particularly as there are almost a dozen jar file came with the fest download.

Comment: Does fest come with an API? I'd check this out as it should tell you the fully qualified name for the MyFrame class and possibly its jar file.

Comment: `MyFrame` is your subclass of JFrame that you are going to test by the framework.

Comment: How to rectify the error in the code??

Comment: Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use AssertJ Swing; FEST is outdated and not maintained anymore. But since AssertJ Swing shares a similar syntax, the transition will be easy.

`MyFrame` is not part of FEST/AssertJ-Swing. It's meant to be the frame you're writing your application for. So instead use JFrame or whatever implementation of a frame you have.

Have a look at the [AssertJ Examples](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-examples) (sorry for posting about AssertJ but if you want to stick with FEST, it should be possible to adapt the code for your purpose). It contains the examples in a compilating version - so you can check it out and play a bit around to see if AssertJ Swing/FEST is the right tool for you.